# Automatic pagination on /blog and /newsletter is adding trailing slash to the end

Tags: wordpress, pagination, slash

My Website Blog page URL is "/blog" without slash.

But on /blog/page/2 , /blog/page/3 etc. the link on "Prev" and "1" pages are linking to "/blog/" with slash.

Same thing with /newsletter pagination: /newlsetter/page/2 linking to /newsletter/ with slash.

Both broken links are redirecting to correctly structured URL, but this is not good from SEO point of view.

How can I change that incorrect link structure in pagination? It's on Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the permalink structure, found in **Settings > Permalinks**, to be set to **Custom Structure** with the value of `/%postname%` in the text field.